# Search cloned select object for option value and set selected if exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectors

What I'm trying to do is clone a template select dropdown element, alter it's attributes some, and then look to see if a string exists as an option value and if it does then go ahead and preselect that option value before I append it.

```
/* Generated HTML inputs for mapping */
    function build_map_input( col_name ) {

        var select = jQuery("#leads_map").clone();

        /* alter dropdown attributes */
        select.attr( 'id' , col_name );         
        select.attr( 'style' , '' );            
        select.attr( 'name' , col_name );   

        /* attempt to preselect values if applicable */
        /*** This is where I need help. My needle is col_name ****/

        var select_html = select.prop('outerHTML');;

        /* build html */
        var html= '<div class="row">';
        html += '   <div class="col-md-3">';
        html +=         col_name;
        html += '   </div>';
        html += '   <div class="col-md-3">';
        html +=         select_html;
        html += '   </div>';
        html += '</div>';

        /* append html to map container */
        jQuery('#map-container').append(html);


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code in my pc and it's working very well. However I suggest this codes :

```
/* build html */
var html= '<div class="row">';
html += '   <div class="col-md-3">';
html +=         col_name;
html += '   </div>';
html += '   <div class="col-md-3">';
html +=         select_html;
html += '   </div>';
html += '</div>';
```

replace to this one :

```
var html = $('<div/>', { class: "row" });
$('<div/>', { class: "col-md-3", text: col_name }).appendTo(html);
$('<div/>', { class: "col-md-3", html: select_html }).appendTo(html);
```

In this way, reading of code will be easy and nice.

Also you can use $ mark instead of jQuery.

Comment: I like how you shortened that. I'll switch to your style. For some reason using $ in the WordPress environment tends to create conflicts. I never understood why. jQuery was always was the safe bet. --- The issue with pre-selecting a select option if it exists as a value, still exists though so I'll have to leave the question unanswered for now.